# goofing it up, got herself up

Tags: grammar, meaning

What do following phrases **goofing it up** and **got herself up** mean and what is the function of **up** here?

> When she tried to be a person she came pretty close to goofing it **up**.
>   There was never anybody on land or sea like Mrs Whatsit the way she
>   got herself **up**.’

A Wrinkle in Time by Madeleine L'Engle

Answer (score 0):

There is not much context to these sentences you have posted.

Goofing up is a phrasal verb which means to fail to do a particular thing.

For example,

> We tried to explain our proposal to the jury, but James goofed up his part.

Picking up oneself means to put behind any failure or hardship and come back.

> Ming Xi picked herself up well after her fall on the Victoria's Secret runway.

Hope this helps.